# How to access Parse object properties in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm building out an AngularJS app that uses data from a parse-server backend. I retrieve any data through services, which can be called from my controllers. But due to how Parse objects work all properties are accessed through a get function, and my html becomes filled with lines like `<p>{{myObject.get('title')}</p>}`.

Ideally I would like to access properties just like a regular object e.g. `myObject.title`, but I can't seem to find a reference for best practices when using the Parse JS sdk with AngularJS.

My searches have turned up several people pointing to [this example of Parse and AngularJS boilerplate by BRANDiD](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/guest-post-parse-x-angular-js-boilerplate/) but links to their actual code and site seem to be dead.

Any insight into how this is best approached would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a service that would return a JSON converted parse response.

**(Pseudo) code:**

***Service:***

```
app.service('Books', function($q) {
  return {
    findBookById: function(id) {

      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // parse query logics .. 
      var Book = Parse.Object.extend("Book");
      var query = new Parse.Query(Book);
      query.equalTo("book_id", id);

      query.first({
        success: function(response) {
          // convert to JSON so that you can access properties directly
          // eg. book.name (instead of book.get('name'))
          deferred.resolve(response.toJSON());
        },
        error: function(err) {
          deferred.reject(err);
        }
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
});
```

***Controller:***

```
app.controller('BookCtrl', function($scope, Books) {
  Books
    .findById(10)
    .then(function(book) {
      $scope.book = book;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      alert('Error occurred : ' + err.message);
    });
});
```

***View:***

```
<p>Book Name: {{book.name}}</p>
```

Comment: This seems like a good answer, and even seems to work with nested pointers. There are people who have had problems with this method in specific cases, as seen [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/258) and [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/364)